# AWS RDS API command to change snapshot name when copying

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is it possible to change a snapshot's identifier when copying it by using the AWS RDS API? I am using Boto3 to write a Lambda function to be used in a DR scenario.

The reason why I'm trying to change the identifier is because I want to add the current date to the snapshot identifier for two reasons:

- It's easier to identify when the snapshot is from
- Different identifiers are needed, so that I can create multiple snapshots. A workaround solution that comes from the top of my mind is to delete the latest snapshot before copying the newest version of it, but I'd like to know if it is possible to change snapshot identifiers like you are able to do it through the management console.

My code:

```
client = boto3.client("rds") #dr region
db_identifier = "test-database-dr" 

# Get snapshot automated arn so we can create a manual copy
describe_snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
    SnapshotType= "shared",
    IncludeShared=True,
)

db_arn = (describe_snapshots["DBSnapshots"][-1]["DBSnapshotArn"])

# Create a snapshot copy 
copy_snapshot = client.copy_db_snapshot(
    SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier=db_arn,
    TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier=db_identifier,
    KmsKeyId="xxx",
    SourceRegion="xxx"
)
```

The error that I get is:

```
botocore.errorfactory.DBSnapshotAlreadyExistsFault: An error occurred (DBSnapshotAlreadyExists) when calling the CopyDBSnapshot operation: Cannot create the snapshot because a snapshot with the identifier test-database-dr already exists.
```

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: @DanielScott Try what? The code that I have posted is my current code and it does not work. The problem that I have is:
botocore.errorfactory.DBSnapshotAlreadyExistsFault: An error occurred (DBSnapshotAlreadyExists) when calling the CopyDBSnapshot operation: Cannot create the snapshot because a snapshot with the identifier test-database-dr already exists.

edit: I've added the error to the original post

Comment: Isn't the error clear? You already have a snapshot with the name you're trying to use. You need to use a different name.

Comment: Yes, and the question is how do I do that? I cannot find in the API how to change the name. If you know how to do it, please, post it and I will try it out. If it works - I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something here? You set the `TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier` in your code. Set it to something different.

Comment: You're copying an existing snapshot, so you must provide an identifier for the new snapshot. That identifier cannot already exist. If it does exist, the copy will fail (as you've seen). You can supply *any* valid identifier, as long as it's not already in use. If you want to reuse an existing identifier, then you need to delete the old snapshot with that id first. There's no API that I'm aware of to rename an existing snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier` to something different.

```
client = boto3.client("rds") #dr region
db_identifier = "test-database-dr-SOMETHING-DIFFERENT" 

# Get snapshot automated arn so we can create a manual copy
describe_snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
    SnapshotType= "shared",
    IncludeShared=True,
)

db_arn = (describe_snapshots["DBSnapshots"][-1]["DBSnapshotArn"])

# Create a snapshot copy 
copy_snapshot = client.copy_db_snapshot(
    SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier=db_arn,
    TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier=db_identifier,
    KmsKeyId="xxx",
    SourceRegion="xxx"
)
```